# can not configure credit card to test funding failure with CCREJECT REFUSED

Tags: paypal

Loggin into my sandbox I can create a credit card. Whenever i try to change the first address line to "CCREJECT-REFUSED" I can't save the card because it gets rejected.
I can create a address with that line. But when I assing the address to a existing card it rejects to save the data again ...

How should I change the address?

Comment: Why do you need to use this address line? Does something else work? Maybe Paypal is rejecting all uppercase letters.

Comment: Everything else works. I need this address line for testing the case described in "How To Recover from Funding Failure Error Code 10486 in Express Checkout".

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? Cannot use CCREJECT-REFUSED for line one for any credit card in the PayPal sandbox account.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by upgrading my Sandbox account making the payment from PERSONAL to BUSINESS.

[image]

At one point this process also fails for me, but if you log out and back in, your account should be upgraded.

From here you should be able to follow these steps (taken from PayPal support) to create a credit card with CCREJECT-REFUSED.

So, login to your sandbox account of choice, click on profile > my money > debit and credit cards and click on "update" or use the direct URL below :

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/mymoney

Click on "Add a Card", select the "Add Credit Card" tab near the top and enter the following details.

Card Number: 5411896071554102
Expiration Date : 12/22
CSC : 123
Billing Address : click on "change" and in the "address line 1" section, enter "CCREJECT-REFUSED" and then click on "Add Card".